# I want to have links that can search through my images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, search

I have "tags" on my webpage and once clicked you can see the corresponding image. Example: I click on the Dogs link and I see images of Dogs on my gallery. Something like this:

```
<a href="#" rel="dog">Show Dogs</a>

<script>
$('#filter a').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('rel')) {
        $('img').hide().filter('[class="' + $(this).attr('rel') + '"]').show();
        $('img').show();
    }

return false;
```

});​

```
<img src="http://www.petliferadio.com/doggydog.jpg" class="dog">
```

however, it doesn't work for me. Would there be easier/ more affective ways of doing it?

Comment: You are showing the filtered set, then immediately after, you're showing them all. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for empty value ..

```
 if($(this).attr('rel')) {
```

should be

```
 if($(this).attr('rel') != '') {
        $('img').hide();
        $('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide all images and then show only required images using class selector in jquery.

```
$('#filter a').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('rel')) {
        $('img').hide();
        $('img.'+$(this).attr("rel)).show();
    }

return false;
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#filter a').on('click', function() {
    var cat = $(this).attr('rel');
    if(cat.length) $('img').hide().filter('.'+cat).show();
});​
```

On clicking the anchor, get the category (shortened to "cat") from the anchor's `rel` attribute, then if the category has `length`, i.e. it's not empty, hide all images, then filter the images based on the class that matches the previous `rel` attribute, and show those images.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question.  Can you add some text describing the solution?